# swapping values on the main diagonal of a two-dimensional array - C

Tags: c, arrays

so this is part of my homework assignment. need some help with it. my task is to swap rows and columns so that the numbers on the main diagonal of a matrix are in descending order. the number of rows and columns is the same. also I need to allocate memory dynamically.

here is an example:
input:

```
    1 2       1<4 so we swap rows and columns and the final result is 4 3 
    3 4                                                               2 1
```

THE PROBLEM is that when I insert a 3x3 array or even larger I get some kind of a segmentation fault. here is my code, please help!

```
    int **t, n, i, j, aux;
    printf("Insert the size of the matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    t = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
            t[i]=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
            for(j=1; j<=n; j++){
                    printf("Element [%d][%d] : ", i, j);
                    scanf("%d", &t[i][j]);
            }
    }

    for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
            if(t[i][i] > t[i-1][i-1]){
                    j=i-1;
                    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
                            aux=t[i][j];
                            t[i][j]=t[i][j+1];
                            t[i][j+1]=aux;
                    }
                    i=j;
                    for(j=1; j<=n; j++){
                            aux=t[i][j];
                            t[i][j]=t[i+1][j];
                            t[i+1][j]=aux;
                    }
                    i=1;
            }
    i++;
    }
    for(i=1; i<= n; i++){
            free(t[i]);
    }
    free(t);
```

Now the error I get is the following:

```
    The matrix inserted:
     1  2  3
     4  5  6
     7  8  9
    The matrix after swapping:
     5  4  6
     2  1  3
     8  7  9
    *** glibc detected *** ./6: double free or corruption (out): 0x08e42018 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0xb7649764]
    /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x96)[0xb764b966]
    ./6[0x80488fb]
    ....
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why aren't you using an [array of arrays](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9.html) instead of `t**`? It'll make your code more readable

Comment: I would've done it, if only I weren't obliged to use dynamically allocated arrays. I agree that it would've been more readable if I had used arrays of arrays. (correct me if I didn't get something..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array indexes start from **0** to **n-1**, if it's size is **n**. With that said, you have quite a few places to take care of it. Play safe with array indexes. For example -

```
for(i=1; i <= n; i++){  // Should be i=0; i < n; i++ 
        t[i]=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: got rid of the error, but it still doesn't swap the elements on the main diagonal ( only the first 2). any ideas why? btw, thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Why don't you just implement a sorting of the elements on the main diagonal and then replace the original diagonal with the sorted one?

Comment: didn't cross my mind actually. one part of the task was to print the matrix at each stage of swapping, that's why i decided this would be the only way.

Comment: Well, you could still do it by sorting, that is, at each sorting step (which is bubble sort in your case I presume) print the matrix with the replaced diagonal. I think it would make things more clear than operating directly on the matrix, because keeping track of diagonal indices can confuse you. Just put the diagonal elements in a separate array and pass it to a sort function. At each step of sort, print the original matrix replacing the original diagonal with the currently sorted array.

Comment: thanks! will give it a try. it makes more logic to me as well (your idea of solving this problem), but i really doubt my teacher will think the same way.